# React error on changing the inline-style of a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, inline-styles

I want to change the style of a component's element on some event, like a click. But when i do, i get the error that my style object is read-only when its not defined as such and thus immutable. Even defining the style object outside the class creates the same error. I created a simple example to illustrate my problem below.

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'color' of object '#<Object>'
```

profile.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class Profile extends React.Component {

  public styler = {
        color:"white",
  }

  render() {
    return (<button style={this.styler} onClick={this.HandleMenuClick.bind(this)}>Click me!</button>);
  }

  HandleMenuClick() {
    this.styler.color = 'gray'; // error on executing this line
  }

}
```

Error created upon clicking the button.

Same error is created when moving the style outside of the class:

```
var styler = {
    color:"white",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `this` key word when inside a class. **But** to see changes in react you should use a `state`.

Here is a small example:

```js
class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      styler:{
        color: "white"
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {styler} = this.state;
    return (
      <button style={styler} onClick={this.HandleMenuClick}>
        Click me!
      </button>
    );
  }

  HandleMenuClick = () => {
    const { styler } = this.state;
    this.setState({styler: {
      ...styler,
      color: 'gray',
      backgroundColor: '#000'
    }})
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<Profile />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment:

> But out of curiosity, my this.styler.color variable never changes in
>   code, i know it wont call render but it doesnt even change the
>   variable in code and just gives the error, why is that?

As i mentioned above, you should use the `this` key word to attach objects to the `class` which basically just a [sugar around the prototype pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

> JavaScript classes are introduced in ECMAScript 6 and are syntactical
>   sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The
>   class syntax is not introducing a new object-oriented inheritance
>   model to JavaScript. JavaScript classes provide a much simpler and
>   clearer syntax to create objects and deal with inheritance.

In your code you used the `public` key word which i'm not familiar with in this context (is it a typo?) **+** you should initialize objects inside the `constructor`.

here is an example with the object being mutated:

```js
class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.myObject = {
      myKey: "Hi there!"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.HandleMenuClick}>Click me!</button>;
  }

  HandleMenuClick = () => {
    console.log(this.myObject);
    this.myObject = {
      myKey: "Bye there!"
    };
    console.log(this.myObject);
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<Profile />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you i see i should put everything in state. But out of curiosity, my this.styler.color variable never changes in code, i know it wont call render but it doesnt even change the variable in code and just gives the error, why is that?

Comment: @user1337604 answer updated, hope it clears some things for you.

Comment: Only for me doesn't work . PLease any suggestion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52167263/why-my-object-from-import-let-is-readonly-react-js?noredirect=1#comment91288499_52167263

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as -

```
import * as React from 'react';

    export default class Profile extends React.Component {
      constructor()
      {
        super();
        this.state.styler = {
            color:"white"
          }
      }


      render() {
        return (<button style={this.styler} onClick={this.HandleMenuClick.bind(this)}>Click me!</button>);
      }

      HandleMenuClick() {
        this.setState({'styler' : {'color':'gray'}});
      }

    }
```